# Label issues with GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, swingworker

I'm fairly new to Java and I am trying to make a GUI. This is the code in my `GUI.java` file. It contains a button and a label. When I click the button, the label is supposed to show "loading..." and enter a static void method in the `Main` class (in `Main.java`) called `searcher` and does stuff. After searcher is done, label becomes `""`.

Problem: Label doesn't change at all when I press press the button. Seems like neither the `setText` in the `actionListener` nor `searcher()` works. However, the other "stuff" I wanted it to do inside `searcher()` still works fine. I don't see any errors.

Note: If I try to call `searcher()` from the main it works fine.

GUI.java:

```
 public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    public JButton button = new JButton("Refresh!");
    public JLabel label = new JLabel("");

    public GUI(){
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        button.addActionListener(this); 
        button.setActionCommand("refresh");
        pane.add(button);
        pane.add(label);
    }
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if ("refresh".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                label.setText("Loading...");
                Main.searcher(this, "", "");
                label.setText("");
            }
}
```

Main.java:

```
public class Main{ 
public static void searcher(GUI gu, String popup, String url) {
    gu.label.setText("Loading...");
    //do stuff
    gu.label.setText("");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI gu = new GUI ();
}
}
```

EDIT: I've changed to code to use SwingWorker and propertylistener as suggested, but I'm having trouble now. Firstly, 'this' no longer refers to the GUI.. what should I pass in the searcher method to pass the current instance of class GUI?

I'm also getting this error and I'm not really sure how to fix it:

.\GUI.java:77: error:  is not abstract and does not override abstract method propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent) in PropertyChangeListener
                                        PropertyChangeListener propChangeListn = new PropertyChangeListener() {^

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if ("refresh".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                label.setText("Loading...");
                SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                    public Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        Main.searcher(this, "", "http://maple.fm/api/2/search?server=0");
                        return null;
                        }
                    };
                //worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new propertyChangeListener listener) {
                PropertyChangeListener propChangeListn = new PropertyChangeListener() {
                public void propertyChanged(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
                    if (pcEvt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                        label.setText("");
                    }
                }
            };
            worker.addPropertyChangeListener(propChangeListn);
            worker.execute();
            }
```

Comment: This is such a common swing problem that it seems like it should be a duplicate of some question, but my search-fu cannot find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yours is a classic Swing threading issue where you are tying the Swing event thread with a long-running process, preventing this thread from updating the GUI's graphics or from interacting with the user. The solution is the same as always -- use a background thread to do your long-running processing. If you used a SwingWorker for this, you could even add a PropertyChangeListener to it and then be notified when the worker has completed its task, allowing you to update the GUI with this information.

Google `Concurrency in Swing` and click on the first hit for more on this.

e.g.,

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if ("refresh".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        label.setText("Loading...");

        // create a SwingWorker object
        final SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new Swingworker<Void, Void>() {

            // long running code would go in doInBackground
            public Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                Main.searcher(...);
                return null;
            }
        }

        // add a listener to worker to be notified when it is done
        worker.addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            public void propertyChanged(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {

                // if the worker is done...
                if (pcEvt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                    label.setText("");

                    // you will probably want to call get() on your worker here
                    // and catch any exceptions that may have occurred.
                }
            }
        }

        // it may seem counter-intuitive, but you need to start the worker with 
        // execute() *after* setting all the above code up.
        worker.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've modified your code a bit to try and get it working but I'm having some trouble with the propertychangelistener: